# Unable to log string with spread operator argument on console

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am new in ES6. I am trying to log a concatenated string (string+spread argument) on console. But, I am unable to concatenate it. Here is the code line:

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var arr2 = [6,7,8,9,10];

//below line 
console.log("Spreading an array iterable: " + ...arr1);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Day 1: Spread Operator</title>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to concatenate the array elements with the string, you can just do --> `"Spreading an array iterable: " + arr1`. Array will be converted to a string before being concatenated.

Comment: It's not an operator. You cannot use this syntax wherever you want. It's part of array literal, object literal and function definitions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37152508/218196

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just [spread `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the array as parameters for `console.log`.

`console.log` is a function which takes arguments and diplays them in a line, separated by space.

Here, the first value is a string and all following parameters are the elements of the array. `...` takes an [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#Built-in_iterables) and convert the elements into arguments.

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log("Spreading an array iterable: ", ...arr1);
```

Comment: Thanks it's working. But could you explain how it's working with , (comma symbol) instead of + (concatenation symbol)?

Comment: @MdFarzan with `arr = [1, 2, 3]` the line `console.log(...arr)` is equivalent to `console.log(1, 2, 3)`. The spread syntax will result in a call to `console.log` with each member of the array as an argument. `console.log("Spreading an array iterable: ", ...arr1);` just means `console.log("Spreading an array iterable: ",  1, 2, 3, 4, 5);` or "print `"Spreading an array iterable: "` and `1`, and `2`, and `3`, and `4`, and `5`"

Answer (score 0):

The spread operator works in an array only
`[...arr1]`

When you try to do

```
console.log("Spreading an array iterable: " + ...arr1);
```

The `+` operator defines a string context. In a string context the spread operator doesn't work. It's a syntax error. You need to use the spread operator in an array literal `[]` or like Nina's answer as a function parameter (or inside an object literal, but that does not apply here).

So in the line

```
console.log("Spreading an array iterable: " + [...arr1]);
```

the `+` operator also establishes a string context, but now the spread operator is inside an array literal. This coerces the [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) method of the array.

See the MDN doc
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var arr2 = [6,7,8,9,10];

//below line 
console.log("Spreading an array iterable: " + [...arr1]);
console.log("Spreading an array iterable: " + [...arr1, ...arr2]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Day 1: Spread Operator</title>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

The [Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Syntax) section says it all

> For function calls:
> `myFunction(...iterableObj);`
>
> For array literals or strings:
> `[...iterableObj, '4', 'five', 6];`
>
> For object literals (new in ECMAScript 2018):
> `let objClone = { ...obj };`

Comment: How is this different than `"Spreading an array iterable: " + arr1`?

Comment: @adiga See the doc I inserted in my answer

Comment: @yunzen the doc doesn't explain what's the difference between `"Spreading an array iterable: " + arr1` and `"Spreading an array iterable: " + [...arr1]`

Comment: @adiga Or see Nina's answer

Comment: No difference (only difference of printing string and numbers), Just trying to understand the spread operator. Why it's not working?

Comment: @MdFarzan I added some more explanation?

Comment: @VLAZ has provide the satisfied answer.